# convert a new line to a tab formatted file

Tags: text-processing, awk, command-line

I have multiple files namely `SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab` `SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab` `SRR3384744.Gene.out.tab` and many more in that order. I am extracting first and fourth columns from these files and store it in an output file. I am trying to ensure that when my script reads a new file it should extract the data tab separated manner instead of data being appended at the end of each file.

Input files:

SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab

```
N_unmapped      313860  313860  313860
N_multimapping  5786679 5786679 5786679
N_noFeature     286816  31696770        438410
N_ambiguous     1283487 32117   65902
AT1G01010       301     0       301
AT1G01020       623     1       622
AT1G03987       5       5       0
AT1G01030       151     2       149
```

SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab

```
N_unmapped      780346  780346  780346
N_multimapping  4621162 4621162 4621162
N_noFeature     182428  28470016        362650
N_ambiguous     1451612 43059   117293
AT1G01010       154     3       151
AT1G01020       685     2       683
AT1G03987       0       0       0
AT1G01030       63      0       63
```

Output I am getting:

```
SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab 
AT1G01010       301
AT1G01020       622
AT1G03987       0
AT1G01030       149
SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab 
AT1G01010       151
AT1G01020       683
AT1G03987       0
AT1G01030       63
```

Output desired:

```
SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab 
AT1G01010       301     151
AT1G01020       622     683
AT1G03987       0       0
AT1G01030       149     63
```

I tried the following script:

```
for sample in *Gene.out.tab; do echo -en $sample "\n"; awk 'NR>4 {print $1 "\t" $4}' $sample; awk '{print $0, $sample}' OFS='\t' $sample; done > output
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want the format you show? I ask because you want a file with 4 fields, but a header line with only 2 fields and that will likely cause you problems downstream. Wouldn't it make more sense to have the `AT1G*` in one column and then each value from each file as a separate column but all values associated with the same ID on the same line without repeating the ID?

Comment: simple but not perfect solution : the `pr` command can format the result into multiple columns. Just see what `cat output | pr --columns=2` does.

Comment: @terdon Yes, your suggestion is even better. That is how I eventually want my output to be.

Comment: Ah, cool because it is also significantly easier :) Can you please [edit] your question and clarify that?

Comment: Is the first column identical for all your files? Or can the elements/order vary?

Comment: @jubilatious In this case the first columns are identical. But if they are not identical then what modifications can be made to the code?

Comment: @Gavin if the first columns are not identical you need a matching step--similar to a database inner join. That's a significant change to your issue for which there may be extant U&L answers. I'll answer this question assuming first columns are identical and look for URLs to point you in the right direction. Otherwise feel free to post a new question with your new requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the output described in the comments, using GNU `awk`:

```
gawk 'FNR==1{names[c++]=FILENAME}
      FNR>4{ lines[$1] = "x"lines[$1] ? lines[$1]"\t"$4 : $4; } 
      END{ 
            for(i=0;i<=c;i++){
                printf "\t%s",names[i]
            } 
            printf "\n"; 
            for(i in lines){ 
                print i,lines[i]
            }
        }' *Gene.out.tab
    SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab
AT1G01010   301 151
AT1G01020   622 683
AT1G01030   149 63
AT1G03987   0   0
```

And, to get it all nicely aligned visually as well, pass it through `column`:

```
$ gawk 'FNR==1{names[c++]=FILENAME}FNR>4{ lines[$1] = "x"lines[$1] ? lines[$1]"\t"$4 : $4; } END{ for(i=0;i<=c;i++){printf "\t%s",names[i];} printf "\n"; for(i in lines){ print i,lines[i]}}' *Gene.out.tab | column -s$'\t' -t
            SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab  SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab
AT1G01010   301                      151
AT1G01020   622                      683
AT1G01030   149                      63
AT1G03987   0                        0
```

`FNR` is a special awk variable that always holds the line number of the current file being processed. `FILENAME` is a GNU `awk` special variable that holds the name of the file currently being processed.

- `FNR==1{names[c++]=FILENAME}`: if this is the first line of one of the input files, then use the variable `c` as the index for the `names` array whose values are the file names, and also increment its value yb 1 (`c++`). After all files have been processed, `files[0]` will be the first file name, `files[1]` will be the second and so on.
- `FNR>4{ lines[$1] = "x"lines[$1] ? lines[$1]"\t"$4 : $4; }`: This is equivalent to this:

  ```
  if(FNR>4){ 
        if("x"lines[$1]){
         lines[$1]"\t"$4
        else{
            lines[$1] = $4
        }
    }
  ```

  If the current input file's line number is 5 or more, check if this first field has an associated value in the array `lines`. We check using `"x"lines[$i]` because if `lines[$1]` is `0`, then the test would be false, but `x0` is true, so the `x` protects from that. So if we do have a value, we append a tab and the current line's 2nd field to it, and if we do not have a value, we set it to be the current line's 4th field.
- `END{ ... }`: do this after processing all input.
- `for(i=0;i<=c;i++){printf "\t%s",names[i]}; printf "\n";` : print each file name in the `names` array, preceded by a tab. We want the leading tab to ensure that we have the same number of fields in the header lines and in the content.  After printing the file names, print a newline.
- `for(i in lines){print i,lines[i]}`: for each index of the `lines` array, print the index (the ID) and then print the associated value that was stored in the first step.

**Limitation**: this requires storing all output data in memory. That really shouldn't be an issue on modern machines since we only store the IDs and just one value per ID per file, so it should be able to handle enormous amounts of input before choking on a reasonably decent machine, but it might become a problem with really enormous amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `join`

```bsh
join -o '1.1 1.4 2.4' SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab
```

```
N_unmapped 313860 780346
N_multimapping 5786679 4621162
N_noFeature 438410 362650
N_ambiguous 65902 117293
AT1G01010 301 151
AT1G01020 622 683
AT1G03987 0 0
AT1G01030 149 63
```

## Use `paste`

I think `paste` is what you are looking for:

```bsh
paste <(cut -f 1,4 SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab) <(cut -f4 SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab)
```

```
N_unmapped      313860  780346
N_multimapping  5786679 4621162
N_noFeature     438410  362650
N_ambiguous     65902   117293
AT1G01010       301     151
AT1G01020       622     683
AT1G03987       0       0
AT1G01030       149     63
```

This solution assumes all `*.tab` should have:

1. the same number of lines.
2. the same ordering.

Here is a script that prints headers and processes multiple files:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
echo $(printf '%s\t' "$@")
first_file=$1
shift
fifos="<(cut -f1,4 $first_file) "$(printf '<(cut -f4 %s) ' "$@")
eval "paste $fifos"
```

```bsh
command *.out.tab
```

```
SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab
N_unmapped      313860  780346
N_multimapping  5786679 4621162
N_noFeature     438410  362650
N_ambiguous     65902   117293
AT1G01010       301     151
AT1G01020       622     683
AT1G03987       0       0
AT1G01030       149     63
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in *.tab; do echo $i >/tmp/"$i"_out.txt ; awk '/^AT/{print $1,$4}' $i >> /tmp/"$i"_out.txt ; done
```

```
paste /tmp/*_out.txt| awk '{$3="";print }'
```

output

```
SRR3384742.Gene.out.tab SRR3384743.Gene.out.tab 
AT1G01010 301  151
AT1G01020 622  683
AT1G03987 0  0
AT1G01030 149  63
```